# How to replace a string at a particular range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "this
           is
           a
           string";
```

Also I have a regex like this:

```
str.replace(/\n/g, " ");
```

The above code applies that regex for all of string, and ouput will be this:

```
output: // this is a string
```

While I want to apply it between this range: `[5, 8]`. In other word, I want this output:

```
what I want: /* this
                is a
                string
             */
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use callback function within `string.replace` also.

```js
var str = "this\nis\na\nstring";
alert(str.replace(/^([\s\S]{5})([\s\S]{3})/, function (x,y,z){return y + z.replace(/\n/, ' ')}))
```

Comment: Works perfectly +1 ..! Every morning I ask a question and you come and write a great answer under my quesiton `:-)` ... Good job

Comment: @stack I should be there if you add my tag to your question.. :-)

Comment: Good to know .. But what is your tag? regex?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the `[5, 8]` range is inclusive.

```
var str = "this\nis\na\nstring";
str = str.substring(0, 5) + str.substring(5, 9).replace(/\n/g, " ") + str.substring(9);
```

Note that the second argument to `str.substring` is the first index *not* to include, not the last digit to include.

To be more general. For any first-included character number `i_start` and last-included character number `i_end`:

```
def replace_part(str, regex, i_start=0, i_end):
    return str.substring(0, i_start) + str.substring(i_start, i_end + 1).replace(regex, " ") + (typeof i_end === 'undefined' ? '' : str.substring(i_end));
```

I've included the check for undefined so that you can omit `i_end` if you just want the whole string after `i_start`.

Comment: Good, but may you please tell me how can I do that for `[x, y]` ? Because `[5, 8]` is just a example ... *(also yes, that range is inclusive)*

Answer (score 0):

According to Pi Marillion's answer, this could be fine too:

```
String.prototype.replace_range=function(regex, i_start, i_end){
    return this.substring(0, i_start) + this.substring(i_start, i_end + 1).replace(regex, " ") + (typeof i_end === 'undefined' ? '' : this.substring(i_end));
}
```

And then you can use that like this:

```
str.replace_range(/\n/g, 5, 8);
```

Comment: Adding a method to `String.prototype` is definitely more elegant. However, many browsers use optimization tricks which de-activate when native prototypes like `String`'s are changed. The difference in speed can be rather large, and may effect all members of `String.prototype`. Make sure to test in the most common browsers before deploying.